# Can I go from the LU factorization of a symmetric matrix to its Cholesky factorization, without starting over?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

I mistakenly computed the LU factorization and then realized that the question is asking for a Cholesky factorization, i.e., finding a lower triangular matrix L such that the *symmetric* matrix A has factorization $LL^T$.

Can I modify this factorization to achieve the Cholesky factorization?

Thanks,

Comment: It would be hard to give an answer of "no," because for example if $L = \lambda U^T$ for some $\lambda > 0$ then it would be easy. You should modify your question to insist that the original matrix is symmetric, otherwise Cholesky decomposition doesn't exist..

Comment: Thanks @user2566092, I just edited my question to include the assumption that A is symmetric.

Comment: If you have an $LDU$ decompositon with $L$ lower unitriangular, $D$ diagonal and $U$ upper unitriangular (the "uni" means that the diagonal entries are $1$), and your matrix is symmetric, then $U = L^T$ (by the uniqueness of the $LDU$ decomposition), and thus you can easily get a Cholesky factorization: $LDU = L \sqrt{D} \cdot \left(L \sqrt{D}\right)^T$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg you were to fast :) Noteworthy, $D$ is positive definite iff $A$ is positive definite. Otherwise the Choleskey decomposition doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi @darijgrinberg, hmm...how can I peel off a D factor from my LU factorization?  Is it an arbitrary choice to sort of..."make it work"?

Comment: I'm looking at my factors L and U, @darijgrinberg, L is lower triangular but unfortunately not lower "unitriangular", however, the factor U is upper unitriangular (of course, from the row-reduction process, which turns all the pivot variables on the main diagonal into 1's.)

Comment: (From this,  letting my U = $L^t$, then my matrix does **not** equal $LL^t$.)

Comment: Use the fact that multiplying a row of a matrix by a scalar $\lambda$ is equivalent to multiplying this matrix with a certain diagonal matrix from the left. It's late here, so sorry for the brevity; this should be in the standard sources, but I don't really know what the standard sources on matrix factorization are.

Comment: Ah, I found an MIT OCW video on it for a very simple 2x2 case.  I will follow the technique there.  Thanks so much for your help @darijgrinberg, and have a great night.  I'm **very** happy that I can go from LU -> to LDU -> Cholesky, without much more work at all. :-)

Comment: A Python code example for sparse symmetric matrices can be found here: https://gist.github.com/omitakahiro/c49e5168d04438c5b20c921b928f1f5d